# What is the generic "rule of thumb" for in which point of view cycle to add subviews to an UIView subclass?

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview, uikit, subclass

What is the generic "rule of thumb" for in which point of view cycle to add subviews to an UIView subclass?

For instance, if you decided to subclass UITableViewCell class in which method should you add subviews to your visual hierarchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other developers I work with and I usually add sub views in `initWithFrame:` and resize or move them in `layoutSubviews`. Notwithstanding views I lay out entirely in nibs which usually I mean to stay at a fixed size anyway. And haste sometimes wins out and we size them in the initializer especially for views we don't need too much resizing of.

Think of it like this: you only need to add something to your view hierarchy once. But you will need to reposition and resize it potentially many times. So you want to do these tasks in methods that share that pattern. `initWithFrame:` will only get called once, `layoutSubviews` many times.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking too.